# Regexp_replace in teradata

Tags: teradata, regexp-replace

Trying to extract dollar amount from the strings with limited success.

```
sel  REGEXP_SUBSTR('ABCD EG 6 MN INT $30870','[\$]\K[0-9]+',1,1,'i');
sel  REGEXP_SUBSTR('BAN000 JAN LTD TO ZZZ$55000','[\$]\K[0-9]+',1,1,'i');
sel  REGEXP_SUBSTR('LTD TO $800000 sds','[\$]\K[0-9]+',1,1,'i');
sel  REGEXP_SUBSTR('IND GEE & INTY FOR $800 000 XDAD CODFSDF','[\$]\K[0-9]+',1,1,'i');
sel  REGEXP_SUBSTR('IND GEE & INTY FOR 800$ XDAD CODFSDF','[\$]|\K[0-9]+',1,1,'i');
```

Pattern is dollar sign ($) followed by a number or number followed by a dollar sign. if you see the fourth case space is there between 800 and 000, the output should come as $80000.

Any insights on how to solve this problem.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: have you tried [$] instead of [\$]?

Comment: This pattern should work, Dollar sign before or after digits + optional spaces: `[$]\K[0-9]+( ?[0-9]+)*|[0-9]+( ?[0-9]+)*(?=[$])`

Comment: Why should `$800 000` become `$80000` ? Are you sure `\K` is supported?